# Index.html is deleted but still browser loads it upon running the web application?

Tags: html, jsp, servlets

I am new to web development and I am self-teaching myself web-development through online tutorials.

**My question:**

This is my first web application and I deleted the original index.html that netbeans provides by default upon creating a web-app and instead created my welcome page as register.html

I duly specified the welcome file as register.html in my deployment descriptor as:

```
<welcome-file-list>  
    <welcome-file>register.html</welcome-file>  
</welcome-file-list>
```

But the problem is whenever I run my project it still shows the index.html(which I have already deleted) as the home page of my project on the browser.
i.e.

```
**localhost:8080/myprojectname/** is still showing the index.html which is not even there and not my register.html which I mentioned in my deployment descriptor.
```

I just started to study web-development two hours ago and I know I am making some serious mistake, please can anyone point out my mistake to me and help me.

Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try clearing up the browser cache?
In case not, then one way is:

- Open google chrome, press F12, this will open the debugger.
- Now on the browser itself, long click over the refresh button, it will show a drop down with 3 options.
- Select the last one: "Empty cache and Hard reload"

This should clear up the cache and on refresh, your html file should not be available anymore.